# Neo4j Server 2.2 Community - How Do I Change Login Password When Current Password Unknown

Tags: neo4j

Windows 7 (SP1) Neo4j Community Edition 2.2

I am using the front end screen to start the server on localhost/7474. The log file says the server is starting successfully. I am unable to remember my password and all documentation I've read about changing the password assumes that you know the current password. I have looked in the dbf/auth file and it contains just a hash. Could some how to change the login passord? Thx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried stopping Neo4j, removing the file and restarting Neo4j. That should prompt you for a new password.

Answer (score 7):

I'm having the same problem with version 3. Was finally able to get `:server change-password` to let me enter the default password and then enter a new one. phew.

Answer (score 3):

Other workaround to shut off basicAuth in Neo4j would be as follows:

Go into the `neo4j/conf/neo4j-sever.properties` file and edit the line:

From

```
# Require (or disable the requirement of) auth to access Neo4j
#dbms.security.auth_enabled=true
```

to

```
# Require (or disable the requirement of) auth to access Neo4j
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, after stopping neo4j, it also worked just to add

> password_change_required

at the end of the hash of User\Eigene Dokumente\Neo4j\default.graphdb\dbms\auth file.
When launching neo4j, pass was default again.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

`sudo vi /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf`

and uncomment the `dbms.security.auth_enabled=false` line.

Then restart the server:

```
sudo service neo4j stop
sudo service neo4j start
```